# XML API gem for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yard

[YARD](http://yardoc.org/) is a gem for generating awesome documentation for your entire app.

But, I'm looking to generate documentation for API calls, that support XML and JSON... while including links to descriptions of object and their parameters, etc.  is there a way to do this?

or maybe some secret command in yard to only generate API docs?

Comment: Did you end up finding a decent tool to suit your need? I'm also looking to write/generate some documentation for a restful API. I love how yard looks, but the 'javadoc' (generated from the source files comments) doesn't suit documenting web service API's quite so well as far as I can see.